# como agrego estilos condicionalmente en reactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

esto usando material-ui para mi diseño front-end y me encuentro con un problema, a mi splash screen le pose un paddingTop de un 30%, pero al rotar el dispositivo, este 30% se nota demasiado y me lleva todo el contenido al pie de la pagina, lo que intento hacer es detectar la orientación y así agregar o no ese 30% de padding, esto es lo que tengo

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(()=>({
   container: {
     display: 'flex',
     width: '100%',
     height: '97vh',
     justifyContent: 'space-around',
     alignItems: 'center',
     flexDirection: 'column',
     paddingTop: window.screen.width > window.screen.height ? 0 : '30%' //esta es la condicion que agregue, pero no tiene efecto 
   },
   img: {
     width: 100,
     height: 'auto'
   }
 }))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo que haría sería crear una clase CSS específica para cuando la condición `window.screen.width > window.screen.height` no se cumple.

De esta forma lo controlas directamente en el componente y no incluyes lógica JS en los ficheros de estilos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div className={[
    styles.container,
    window.screen.width > window.screen.height ? null : styles.anotherStyle
].filter(Boolean).join(' ')}>
    Foobar
</div>
```

Y en el fichero de estilos creas una clase específica `anotherStyle`.